# How are test credit card numbers standardized?

Tags: mocking, language-agnostic, standards, credit-card, iso

Looking through documentations of various payment processors such as Stripe and PayPal, I've noticed there are quasi-universal test credit card numbers e.g. `4111 1111 1111 1111`, `4242 4242 4242 4242`, `5555 5555 5555 4444`, etc[1][2]. I'd like to learn about the rules behind them.

- Are those test card numbers predefined standards or are they just conventional?
- Is it OK for a payment service provider (PSP) to make up one?

  - If so, how should a PSP define a mock card without coinciding with a genuine card?
  - Are there any PAN ranges reserved universally for test/mock purposes?

I don't have full access to the proprietary ISO/IEC 7812, which could be what I'm missing.

References

- [1] Test your integration https://stripe.com/docs/testing
- [2] Test Transactions card number https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payflow/integration-guide/test-transactions/

Answer (score 0):

Payment Schemes (Visa, Mastercard, ...) usually assign one or more BINs for test cards. These BINs are not part of routing tables and hence, card numbers (i.e., PANs) within those BINs will not be routed on the networks. They can be safely used for testing purposes.

Acquiring/issuing processors, PSPs, and other stakeholders usually use these BINs for their own testing as well.

Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Does that mean a PSP can arbitrarily make up PANs like Stripe has[1] as long as they're within the predefined test BIN range?
[1] https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards

Comment: Yes they can. However PSPs might have whitelisted test PANs so that you would be forced to use one from their list.